# Vector Iterator Errors With a Vector of Type Struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, iterator

I'm trying to use a vector iterator to print out all of the elements in a vector. I've looked up similar questions but the solutions posted don't seem to be working for me. Here's the code:

```
void printPerms()
{
   for(vector<process>::iterator it = allProcesses.begin(); it != allProcesses.end(); it++)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < numResourceTypes; i++)
      {
         cout << (static_cast<process*>(*it).need) << (static_cast<process>(*it)).allocated <<endl;
      }
   }
}
```

And the errors I am getting, which I don't know how to fix:

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'process' to 'process *' No user
defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator
cannot be called

error C2228: left of '.need' must have class/struct/union
```

Answer (score 6):

Try...

```
void printPerms()
{
   for(vector<process>::iterator it = allProcesses.begin(); it != allProcesses.end(); it++)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < numResourceTypes; i++)
      {
         cout << it->need << it->allocated << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know what exactly is going wrong, nor do I see why you need to use `static_cast`, however you should be able to access those member variables regardless using the `->` operator.

De-referencing an iterator gives you its value (in this case, the `process`), with no need for a cast.

Comment: I originally tried that, actually, but it also gives me an error. There's a lovely red squiggle under the first << after cout, that says "Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands"

Comment: What type is `it->need`?

I think that's because the type of `it->need` doesn't have a definition of `std::ostream &operator<<`; in other words, it's not printable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*it` is of type `process`, you might try getting its address before casting by changing

```
(static_cast<process*>(*it).need)
```

to

```
((static_cast<process*>(&(*it)))->need)
```

However, it might be simpler to do `it->need`

By the way, if you are just printing (and not modifying the `vector` contents), then it is recommended to use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`.